# get and set cookie values in array position

Tags: javascript, cookies, join, split, setcookie

OK, I have the logic, but unsure how to write to specific positions in a cookie that are separated with a pipe, |

For example - take a cookie with 0|0|0|0

if global variable is set to Y, then write the values c and d to the 2nd & 3rd position(assuming array) if the cookie exists - if the cookie doesn't exist then create a cookie with 0|0|c|d

if the global variable is null then write the values a and b to the 0 and 1st position if the cookies exists - if the cookie doesn't exist then create a cookie with a|b|0|0

I understand getting a cookie, and splitting the cookie to get a value, but unsure how to write to specific positions. I'm assuming using "join".

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your desired cookie value was named `"pipes"` and your variable was named `globalVar`, you could do something like this:

```
var val = readCookie("pipes") || "";
var valArray = val.split("|");
if (valArray.length >= 4) {
    if (globalVar == "Y") {
        valArray[2] = 'c';
        valArray[3] = 'd';
    } else if (globalVar == null) {
        valArray[0] = 'a';
        valArray[1] = 'b';
    }
    val = valArray.join("|");
} else {
    // fully formed cookie value didn't exist
    if (globalVar == "Y") {
        val = "0|0|c|d";
    } else {
        val = "a|b|0|0";
    }
}
createCookie("pipes", val, 365);
```

I must say that storing this piped value in the cookie is very inconvenient and requires more code than is probably required to just store and retrieve multiple values from a cookie.

From your comments, it sounds like the data is storeID|storeLocation and you have two of those.  I'd suggest you just do this:

```
var store1 = readCookie("store1");    // "1640|Jacob's Point"
var store2 = readCookie("store2");    // "2001|Fred's Point"
```

Or, if you want to make a function, you can do this:

```
function readStoreInfo(item) {
    var info = readCookie(item);
    if (info) {
        var data = info.split("|");
        return({id: data[0], name: data[1]});
    }
    return(null);
}

function writeStoreInfo(item, obj) {
    var val = obj.id + "|" + obj.name;
    createCookie(item, val, 365);
}
```

So, to read the data for store1, you would just call:

```
var store1Info = readStoreInfo("store1");
store1Info.id = 123;
writeStoreInfo("store1", store1Info);
```

You can then read and write the data for store1 and store2 independently.

Comment: What would you suggest for storing values - my values are strings in this type of format, for example: 1640|Jacob's Point|2001|Fred's Point

Comment: In order to use that data, you are going to have to split it into it's four components.  So, why not just store each component in it's own named cookie value and then you can just retrieve each component into it's own variable.  Then you don't have to combine them and separate them just to store and use them.  Four variables, four cookies values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep it all within one cookie - I wanted to separate the data into two cookies, but we have too many cookies already and are now limiting how many cookies we use, etc.

Comment: @Jason - technically it's all one giant cookie string.  Each name/value pair you read from the cookie string is just one piece of the larger cookie string.  Just look at how readCookie works to see that in action.  But, if you don't want two name/value pairs for the stores, then you can stick with the first way or doing things and the extra complication to update one store's value.

Comment: right, but with IE and the 20 cookie limit (our cookies have proliferated like crazy) we are kind of up against the wall, until we go through a clean them up

Comment: In 2007, IE7 was updated to support 50 cookies.  You should only see the 20 cookie max in IE6.  But, if you want to stay with fewer, you have the code for it in the first option.

Comment: Question - would I be better served by using subkeys? Or would I not be gaining anything by doing so?

Comment: If, by subkeys you mean encoding multiple keys inside of one key with your own format, that can help if you are nearing the 50 cookie limit in some browsers.  But, there is also a total length limit for the cookie and subkeys won't help with that.